# Replace 3-way switch with 4 screws with 3-way dimmer with only 3 screws

Tags: electrical

[image][image]I want to replace an existing 3-way switch with a 3-way dimmer. The old switch has 2 brass screws and 2 black screws, plus a green ground screw. Ignoring the ground, there are wires attached to all four screws and all four wires are brown. The dimmer switch has 2 brass screws but only one black screw. How do I connect the 2 wires that are  on the 2 black screws on the old switch to the new dimmer switch?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved? I think you are looking at a 4-way switch here...

Comment: Not trying to be "mysterious". Trying to find a link to add photos.

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the back of the box?

Comment: Also, what make and model of dimmer do you have, and is exchanging it for a different dimmer an option?

Comment: I just figured out that I am dealing with a 4-way, not a 3-way. Will buy the appropriate dimmer. Thanks

Comment: They don't make them.  The bad news is *nope, you cannot pit a dimmer here at the 4-way position*. The good news is, your house is wired in the **conduit wiring method**, which means you can rearrange things any way you like, such as moving the 4-way position to one of the now-3-way positions.  Do you own this home?